# Can I install a surge protector device in a main lug sub panel

Tags: electrical

By I did install 2 projector and the costumer wants to protect the projector installing a surge protector plugs the projector are install 30’ high.
My questions is can i install a surge protector device at the sub panel where I get power from even this sub panel doesn’t have a main breaker just a main lug

Comment: If you are doing electrical work for hire you need a license to do that, which comes with a bunch of training to do that. If you lack the training and the license, you should not being doing electrical work for customers.And if you do have those but still have questions, this is not the site for you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not on topic, being a question from somone doing electrical work for a customer.

Comment: @Ecnerwal All true. But that being said, if the question didn't say "the customer" then it could just as easily be someone doing their own electrical where allowed to do so. And in that situation this would be a perfectly reasonable question. I'd argue it is a little different from the "apartment rental" situation because there nobody but a licensed electrician is (usually) allowed where here in many jurisdictions homeowner is allowed.

Comment: Typically, AHJs waive the "pro electrician only" rule for basic stuff like swapping a receptacle, switch, light fixture, breaker, water heater, etc.  Installing a snap-in "fits like a breaker" SPD would likely qualify.  Yes, it'd be fine in a subpanel, and provide much better surge protection than any plug-in or "power strip" type would ever provide.  This is a suitable application for pigtailing the surge suppressor off the same breaker as the thing being protected.  Note that certain breakers are labeled for 2 wires per terminal (don't do it otherwise). E.G. Square D QO type, and Pushmatic.

Answer (score 1):

### A Type 2 SPD can go anywhere downstream of the main

A Type 2 SPD can be placed, on an appropriate breaker of course, in any panel in the distribution system.